# JBCefBrowser how to handle JS events in Java code

Tags: java, intellij-plugin, chromium-embedded

I'm using JBCefBrowser for build my application (IntelliJ plugin). I need to handle button or link click in Java code (not JavaScript). Could someone give an advice how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no such events. Look for the navigation events in the client handler, it is the closest to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val javaScriptEngineProxy: JBCefJSQuery = JBCefJSQuery.create(browser as JBCefBrowserBase)

javaScriptEngineProxy.addHandler { result ->
    println(result)

    null
}

val injectedJavaScript = """
    window.goToLine = function() {                
        var filePath = document.getElementById("go-to-filepath").value
        var lineNumber = document.getElementById("go-to-line-number").value
        var goToPath = filePath + ":" + lineNumber
        ${javaScriptEngineProxy.inject("goToPath")}
    }
            
    """.trimIndent()

browser.cefBrowser.executeJavaScript(injectedJavaScript, browser.cefBrowser.url, 0)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).